# Execute control update with Binding without call .Content?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know how can I update the value of a control without using directly the `Content` property. In particular I've this situation, this is my control:

```
<Label x:Name="Test" Content="{Binding Tester, IsAsync=True}" />
```

now, in my `ViewModel` I've a property called *Tester* that have this structure:

```
public string Tester
{
    get { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); }
}
```

this working good but for assign the value to *Test* `Label` I usually do this in my `MainWindow`:

```
Test.Content = ViewModel.Tester;
```

Is it possible to call directly `ViewModel.Tester` and update the *Test* `Label` value automatically?

Comment: Have you tried `DataContext`?

Comment: @jafar I already using the DataContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel class you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and when you've modified the Content, you can notify the UI manually by throwing the event:

```
Test.Content = ViewModel.Tester;
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Test.Content)));  // or throw it on the long (old) way
```

**Edit:**

Since it's being binded already to the Tester, I would recommend to use it this way:

```
string _testString;

public string TestString
{
    get { return _testString; }
    set
    {
        _testString = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TestString)));
    }
}
```

And in the xaml I would bind the `TestString` property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding TestString}" />
```

So, when you are setting the `TestString` property somewhere, the `Label's` `Content` is being updated automatically.

E.g. if you would like to set it in a `TextBox` to test it:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

*Note: the requirement of this solution is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with the ViewModel class, and set it as the `DataContext` of the view.*

You can use this method for the purpose to fire the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You shouldn't use it as `internal`/`public`, since it would hurt the separation of concerns. The owner class (or inherited classes) should handle the notifying process.

Comment: I already do this.. I've the NotifyPropertyChanged. I'm wondering if is possible update the control value calling only the property instead of `Test.Content = ViewMode.Tester`, ok?

Comment: OT Question: PropertyChanged should be only private? or can I call it in external class and so use public in the declaration?

Comment: I would create a protected method for this purpose (I'll add it to my answer), but wouldn't use it as `internal`/`public`, since it would hurt the separation of concerns. The owner class (or inherited classes) should handle the notifying process. So: in external class, you can set the value, but when it's being set, the container class will fire the event (like we did in the case of our `TestString` property, whenever/wherever it's being set, the UI is being notified.)

Comment: You do not call `PropertyChanged` from external classes. You just **set** the value of your VM object's property (`TestString` in your case). `PropertyChanged` is then automatically called by the VM object since it is there in the property setter.

Comment: What does TwoWay means?

Comment: That means it can be set as well, not just read. (In case of `Label`s it's pointless, since that control's `Content` is read only.) So, in case of the `TextBox` example, when you are typing in the `TextBox`, the property itself is being set (in real time, which is because of the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` option).

Comment: So I don't need to use UpdateSourceTrigger in the label ? @KAI

Comment: You are right, you don't need to use that. (Fun)fact: if you wouldn't use it either at the `TextBox` (only the `TwoWay` modifier), the control's `Content` (the text which you see in the `TextBox`) would be sent to the property only when you would press `Enter`, by default.